# All commands in script not being run

Tags: unix

I've created a simple unix script "update.sh" which performs the following :

```
sudo su -
export SBT_OPTS="$SBT_OPTS -Dhttp.proxyHost=myproxy-Dhttp.proxyPort=1111"
export PATH=$PATH:/home/update/sbt/bin
```

I run using `./update.sh`

But just the initial command `sudo su -` is executed. How can I update the script so that all commands are run ?

Comment: when you switch user to root, the profile of the root user is used when you run `export`. are you trying to view the environment variables of the current user or the root user? its possible that `SBT_OPTS` is only set for the current user.

Comment: @anurupr im attempting to exports those variables so that they are available to the root user, not the current user.

Comment: so you are appending a value to `SBT_OPTS`, is `SBT_OPTS` already set for the root user before running the script?

Comment: @anurupr SBT_OPTS is not set for root user

Comment: then logically `export SBT_OPTS="$SBT_OPTS -Dhttp.proxyHost=myproxy-Dhttp.proxyPort=1111"` shouldn't work . isn't it?

Comment: @anurupr I think I may have mis-communicated. If I manually run above commands then everything works as expected. I'm switched to root user, SBT_OPTS & Path are updated correctly. But when I try to script this the variables are not updated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you run `sudo su -` without any further arguments, you're launching a new interactive shell, with effective userid set to root.  You need to exit that shell before the rest of your script is executed in your current shell.

To do what you want, type

```
SBT_OPTS=... PATH=... sudo su -
```

(with ... replaced as required).  This sets your environment and then launches the command with that setting intact.

Comment: that does'nt work as I want to execute the command for the root user via a script

Comment: I don't quite understand.  Can't you put the line I suggested into a script?

Comment: BTW, ignore the back ticks.  They're a typo and I've removed them.

Comment: I think there are more commands to be performed as root. Now a sudo scipt is started and waiting for further commands.
With `sudo su - -c echo perform this` you can perform a single command. Or use `sudo - -c myscript_with_exports_and_more_commands.sh`